# Sending data using post without a form

Tags: php, html

I would like to send data using POST , without creating a form . I know lot of people would suggest sessions. But here is my usecase.

A php script creates a folder with timestamp as a name . The timestamp is passed on to all subsequent pages invoked , which will store files related to that transaction , logs etc. If I use a session and a user opens another instance of application , the session time will get changed and cause much harassment.

So is there  a way where i can pass time along without needing a form for POST.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: can you please elaborate on the java script solution.

Comment: what is the reason not to use form

Answer (score 0):

send timestamp via jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.post("index.php",{"timestamp":new Date().getTime()});
});
```

in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["timestamp"])) { $timestamp = $_POST["timestamp"]; }
```

Comment: Just remember that the timestamp is the timestamp as set on the user's computer, and may not be the same as on the server. Make sure this won't be causing you any grief.